# Use same database on main domain & sub domain

Tags: database, subdomains

I have a main domain `https://www.jaytech.com.ng` and I also have a subdomain `https://m.jaytech.com.ng`

I want both the domains to use the same database when visited. I've tried using Multisite but it isn't working.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: you mean use the same exact data? or the same database but different data?

Comment: I mean using same database and data...

Comment: I.e the both displaying the same posts from a database

Answer (score -1):

You cant have 2 sites that uses the same data from the same `database`, because of how WordPress works (permalinks etc), i am guessing you want to do this to show 2 different themes, 1 for the `desktop version` and 1 for the `mobile version`, try doing that with 1 WordPress installation and change the theme based on the device with a `detecting class` either from a `plugin` or `make one`.

I recommend you to use a stylesheet instead of having 2 themes.

Comment: That would not be possible for separate installations using the same database. **Wordpress** stores the the links for pages/post to the database. In this case, clicking any posts/pages in the *m.jaytech* would be redirected to the original domain *jaytech* in which the database initially belongs.

Comment: true, permalinks, i will update the answer

Comment: Okay, I also tried using `.htaccess` to redirect it, but did not work also